# FrameLayout wrap_content

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a problem with FrameLayout. I want to create FrameLayout which will have it's first child's height and the second child will get it's parent's height(`100dp` in this example). But what I get is the FrameLayout is filling the screen(`match_parent`).
Here is my xml.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

How can I make FrameLayout to be as big as it's first child and the second child as big as it's parent? Do I need to use different parent?

Comment: use LinearLayout instead of FrameLayout.

Comment: ref: FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to display a single item. Generally, FrameLayout should be used to hold a single child view, because it can be difficult to organize child views in a way that's scalable to different screen sizes without the children overlapping each other.

Comment: I want to layout them on top of each other and show only one view at a time. So LinearLayout is not usable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using RelativeLayout will surely serve you what you are trying to achieve:

```
  <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_id_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_id_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/view_id_1"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/view_id_1" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks that does the trick ) (Didn't think of RelativeLayout)

Comment: I think it should be:
android:layout_alignBottom="@id/view_id_1"
android:layout_alignTop="@id/view_id_1" you still have the + sign